# How to loop multiple columns of excel extracted data to calculate on vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net, loops

I'm having some trouble trying to loop more than two columns of information from my Excel spreadsheet in order to create the output that I want from calculating with the data.

**My task is to find "the total number of customer contacts during the last month per sales person."**

I'm trying to extract the data from the month of December (column 1) to find how many customer IDs (column 2) are assigned to each sales person (column 3). The output in the textbox should show *sales person* "=" *# of total customers*

I'm coding in Visual Studio Community 2017 and I used the EPPlus extension to extract my excel spreadsheets.

This is my code so far:

```
Dim dateToCheck As DateTime
dateToCheck = New Date(2017, 12, 1) 'year month day
Dim diDateCustId As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
Dim excelDate As DateTime
Dim excelCustId As String
Dim excelSalesPerson As String

For startRow = 2 To lastRow

    excelDate = Convert.ToDateTime(worksheetHS.GetValue(startRow, 1).ToString())
    excelCustId = worksheetHS.GetValue(startRow, 2).ToString()
    excelSalesPerson = worksheetHS.GetValue(startRow, 3).ToString()

    If dateToCheck.Month = excelDate.Month Then
        If 
        If diDateCustId.ContainsKey(excelSalesPerson) Then
            Dim liSt As List(Of String) = diDateCustId(excelSalesPerson)
            If liSt.Contains(excelCustId) Then
                ' do nothing
            Else
                liSt.Add(excelCustId)
                diDateCustId(excelSalesPerson) = liSt
            End If
        Else
            Dim liSt As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            liSt.Add(excelCustId)
            diDateCustId.Add(excelSalesPerson, liSt)
        End If
    End If
Next startRow

' outputting value to Textbox
For Each keyValPair In diDateCustId
    TextBox1.Text += keyValPair.Value.ToString() + " > " + keyValPair.Value.Count.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
Next
```

The function is calculated by checking off a radio button and then clicking the Calculate button. This code example was from my 2nd radio button condition, but I changed all the parts in the code that refer to *"excelData"* as *"excelSalesPerson"* but then now the code doesn't work and creates errors. I'm not sure how to code it correctly to loop all three columns to find the output I want.

This is the code for my previous calculation that actually worked, for reference. The task was to find "the total number of customer contacts per day during the last month."

```
Dim dateToCheck As DateTime
dateToCheck = New Date(2017, 12, 1) 'year month day
Dim diDateCustId As Dictionary(Of Date, List(Of String)) = New Dictionary(Of Date, List(Of String))
Dim excelDate As DateTime
Dim excelCustId As String

For startRow = 2 To lastRow

    excelDate = Convert.ToDateTime(worksheetHS.GetValue(startRow, 1).ToString())
    excelCustId = worksheetHS.GetValue(startRow, 2).ToString()

    If dateToCheck.Month = excelDate.Month Then

        If diDateCustId.ContainsKey(excelDate) Then
            Dim liSt As List(Of String) = diDateCustId(excelDate)
            If liSt.Contains(excelCustId) Then
                ' do nothing
            Else
                liSt.Add(excelCustId)
                diDateCustId(excelDate) = liSt
            End If
        Else
            Dim liSt As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            liSt.Add(excelCustId)
            diDateCustId.Add(excelDate, liSt)
        End If
    End If
Next startRow

' outputting value to Textbox
For Each keyValPair In diDateCustId
    TextBox1.Text += Convert.ToDateTime(keyValPair.Key).ToShortDateString() + " > " + keyValPair.Value.Count.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
Next
```

Comment: "doesn't work and creates errors" - you will need to be much more specific about what the errors are and where they occur.

Comment: I'm not seeing a compelling reason to do this outside the vanilla features of Excel. Why all the VS hubbadubbdub?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a Pivot Table?

Comment: Sorry, I have to create an application on vb.net and this was just one of the forms required in my project so I have to do all this extra complicated coding to extract the data and make arrays to calculate in vb.net. I'm still learning so I'm not completely sure what I am doing.

Comment: @Tim when I debug the application it says "Variable 'excelDate' hides a variable in an enclosing block."  -- does this mean something is not reading?

Comment: It means you used the name `excelDate` already and can't use it again with a `Dim`. You don't show enough of the code to know where the blocks are.

Comment: Ooh, okay yes I did, I kinda fixed that now. So that helped compile my app, but now it's just looping that needs to be corrected and using the correct variable to show on the output....I'm still a bit confused but slowly getting there. :/

Comment: Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with your code, except your output needs to be `keyValPair.Key` before the `">"` to get the Sales Person.

Comment: Wow, that is all I had to do, thanks! My looping logic was correct and I just  didn't code the variable correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given some data like so:

```
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Month  │ Customer IDs │ Sales Person │
├────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┤
│ Oct-17 │            1 │ John Smith   │
│ Oct-17 │            2 │ Jane Doe     │
│ Dec-17 │            1 │ John Smith   │
│ Dec-17 │            2 │ John Smith   │
│ Dec-17 │            2 │ John Smith   │
│ Dec-17 │            1 │ Jane Doe     │
│ Dec-17 │            2 │ Jane Doe     │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

You can select the table and Insert a Pivot Table.

1. Drag the `Month` field to the Filters area below.
2. Drag the `Customer IDs` to the Values area.
3. Click the drop down next to `Customer IDs` and pick `Value Field Settings...`. Select `Count` from the list, set a custom name and click `OK`.
4. Drag the `Sales Person` to the Rows area. Replace Row Labels with "Sales Person".
5. In the Pivot Table filter, select the month of December.
6. See your results.

   ```
   ┌────────────────┬────────────────┐
   │     Month      │     Dec-17     │
   ├────────────────┼────────────────┤
   │ Sales Person   │ # of Customers │
   ├────────────────┼────────────────┤
   │  Jane Doe      │ 2              │
   │  John Smith    │ 3              │
   ├────────────────┼────────────────┤
   │ Grand Total    │ 5              │
   └────────────────┴────────────────┘
   ```

Comment: Is this a solution for vba in Excel? I'm sorry I need the coding for vb.net in Visual Studio. You can't make pivot tables in VS right?

Comment: It wouldn't be worthwhile to do so, but VS seems overkill for this issue - why do you need to do VS?

Comment: My project is under vb.net. I never learned vba on excel so when I had to use excel with VS in this project, all the vba and excel use was all brand new to me so this is frustrating me like crazy since I've only learned basic vb.net coding too and i've spent a whole week going in circles....and it's due tonight :(